# Fusion, Magnets and Quantum Generators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, particle-physics, experimental-physics, atomic-physics

I cannot even play like I'm even at this level, but this is the fusion reactor in Germany called the Wendelstein 7-X stellarator.

[image]

These doughnut-shaped magnets (often seen on Physic Exchange) are meant to cage plasma in magnetic fields while being heating to the 45 million K for the D-T fusion needed for hydrogen nuclei to fuse. These particular magnets are designed to spin the plasma.My question is could solid magnets in the device be used alone to spin liquid matter or a solid object?

This might be a question for Engineering.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question: what is a "solid magnet"? Do you mean permanent magnet? And by solid object you mean anything solid (even a strawberry or bread)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containing plasma in a magnet field turned out to be far harder than anyone expected, and indeed it's one of the main obstacles to economical fusion power. One of the main aims in building the Wendelstein 7-X reactor is to achieve long term (30 minutes) stable plasma containment.

Containing the plasma requires very fine control of the magnetic fields used, both the overall strength of the magnetic field and the fine details of its shape. This is, if not easy, then at least achievable with electromagnets because the field can be changed by changing the current in the coil. With a permanent magnet you wouldn't have the ability to change the field.

So the answer is that no you couldn't use only permanent magnets in a fusion reactor.

I wouldn't rule out the possibility that permanent magnets could be used in a supporting role i.e. to assist the electromagnets. I don't know enough about fusion reactor design to comment on this.

Comment: I think it uses both